# CMSIS DSP example - FFT

Tags: eclipse

I am currently working on the FFT example using MAX32660. The toolchain that I am using is ARM Cortex Toolchain. It uses Eclipse for the compiling and bugging purpose. I imported the example code and when I debugged the code I get this error. 
[image]

The point is this path does not exist in my system. I checked the Compiler and the linker path, they appear to be correct. Can I someone tell me what is throwing this error.

Comment: There is a hierarchy of #ifdefs scattered throughout that header (and others). I had this problem a while back. As I am not sure of the details of *your* headers you need to examine the header file itself and ensure that the necessary conditionals are satisfied.

Comment: @peter, thanks for replying. the header file that is throwing is [here] (https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/blob/develop/CMSIS/DSP/Include/arm_math.h). The example I am trying is an example from the CMSIS pack.

Comment: I tried compiling the Makefile as an alternative. But I am not able to load the code into the MAX32660 board.

Comment: I just observed this..Hopefully it will help someone. In the arm_math.h, a function arm_sqrt_f32 is used. It should be defined in arm_sqrt_f32.h. I cannot find this file anywhere. I am not sure if the function is defined in a header file with a different name.

Comment: It looks like in eclipse even if we add the math library path and the math library it does not read it  for some reason. They need to be added separately by Properties-> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> Cross ARM GNU C Linker -> MIsc -> Other Linker Files.-> -L the_path_of_math_library -lm libarm_cortexM4l_math.a.